# For loop prints identical values instead of incremented values as intended

Tags: php

I wish to add ranks from 1 to as many rows are found in the query `$query_for_credits_table` in the ranks column in the table on the webpage. For that i've created the for loop (see below) which will run till the condition `$i<$query_for_credits_table->num_rows`. But what happens the values which the loop prints in the rank column are identical in all cells (which is 9 in mine case as 9 rows are returned from the query.
How can I fix this??

EDIT1:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Credits Chart</title>
    <style>
        table, td, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once '../../backend/actions/credits_table.php' ?>

    <h1>Volunteers Credits Score Table</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Credits</th>
            </tr>
        <?php while ($storing_data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_for_credits_table)) { ?>

            <tr>
                 <?php
                    for($i=1; $i <$query_for_credits_table->num_rows; $i++) ?>
                        <td><?php echo($i);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo($storing_data['firstName'].' '.$storing_data['lastName']);?></th>
                        <td><?php echo($storing_data['credits']);?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
    </table>



    <?php require_once '../includes/footer.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for ../../backend/actions/credits_table.php file:

```
<?php
include_once '../connection.php';
$query_for_credits_table=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT firstName, lastName, credits FROM volunteers ORDER BY credits DESC;");
```

Comment: Looks you are nesting wrong. Use foreach instead of for.

Comment: What is in $storing_data? Can you do a var_dump sample so we can see the structure

Comment: @TimBrownlaw $storing_data was introduced first time here. BTW it stores the result of  ````$query_for_credits_table```` query as an associative array. But i don't think it's of any concern here. If you say I'll also add the query which I run and store in ````$query_for_credits_table````

Comment: Ok, if you do not want to provide anything further - good luck with it.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I've updated my question

Comment: @MarkusZeller can you please tell me the code for ````foreach()```` loop? I'm not able to create one...